# Aggregate data by multiple groups

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping

My questions is best described with an example:

data:

```
v1 <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p")
v2 <- c("aa","bb","cc","dd","ee","ff","gg","hh","ii","jj","kk","ll","mm","nn","oo","pp")
v3 <- c("aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","eee","fff","ggg","hhh","iii","jjj","kkk","lll","mmm","nnn","ooo","ppp")
values <- 1:10000
y <- data.frame(var1=sample(v1,size = 100,replace=T),
                var2=sample(v2,size=100,replace=T),
                var3=sample(v3,size=100,replace=T),
                val1=sample(values,size=100,replace=T),
                val2=sample(values,size=100,replace=T))


head(y)
  var1 var2 var3 val1 val2
1    h   hh  lll 4832 9547
2    h   nn  eee  727 6382
3    h   bb  jjj 9985 8041
4    e   bb  jjj 1438  280
5    k   ff  nnn 3094 4316
6    f   cc  kkk 7426 3588
```

Basically I need to sum val1 and val2 by all unique combinations of var1,var2, and var3.  So, none of the rows in the `head` statement above would get summed together.

In the actual data I'm working with,  there are thousands of different values for var1, var2, and var3. Additionally,  there are a varying number of columns I want to group by.  This is going to be used in a shiny app where the user selects any number of groups that he/she wants to aggregate by.  I've tried using `stats::aggregate` but it doesn't seem to be versatile enough for this.

If you need anything else to help answer my question let me know.

EDIT:
Very helpful responses so far and thank you for that, but they aren't quite what I'm looking for (my fault, I didn't state the question clear enough).

The issue is automating my script so it can aggregate the example above as well as the following:

```
head(y)
  var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 val1 val2 val3
1    p   pp  nnn   ll  aaa 3914 6621 8968
2    d   ii  jjj   pp  aaa 5885  955 7560
3    j   bb  ppp   aa  ccc 7979 5602 4639
4    e   mm  ooo   mm  fff 8746 8612 2212
5    g   ee  aaa   kk  lll 4795 6438 6318
6    f   mm  kkk   ii  ggg 7550   90 1173
```

In my shiny app the data could just as easily look like this, or some other variation with any number of columns.  I know the index values for the variable and value columns, but not their names.  So I can use the index values, but they are changing.  Also I can't really hard code in any columns since they are always changing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: `aggregate(cbind(val1, val2)~var1+var2+var3, data=y, sum, na.rm=TRUE)` should work though.

Comment: You can even set the column names using `cbind("val1"=val1, "val2"=val2)` in the the above example.

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
y<-data.table(y)
setkey(y, var1, var2, var3)

y[,.(sum1 = sum(val1), sum2 = sum(val2)), by = c("var1", "var2", "var3") ]

var1 var2 var3  sum1 sum2
a   cc  ggg  4483 5176
a   gg  ccc  1928 1833
a   mm  ppp  1550 3930
a   nn  kkk  1340 2080
b   dd  ccc  8950  158
b   hh  bbb  4798  689
b   kk  mmm   129 9740
b   pp  ccc  8363 1531
c   gg  ggg  1662  125
c   gg  hhh  4485 3800
...
```

The other popular option is `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

y %>% group_by(var1, var2, var3) %>% 
  summarise(sum1 = sum(val1), sum2 =sum(val2))

 var1   var2   var3  sum1  sum2
(fctr) (fctr) (fctr) (int) (int)
    a     cc    ggg  4483  5176
    a     gg    ccc  1928  1833
    a     mm    ppp  1550  3930
    a     nn    kkk  1340  2080
    b     dd    ccc  8950   158
    b     hh    bbb  4798   689
    b     kk    mmm   129  9740
    b     pp    ccc  8363  1531
    c     gg    ggg  1662   125
    c     gg    hhh  4485  3800
```

Some say the syntax of `dplyr` is a little easier to read/write, but I prefer both methods equally. Speed is usually comparable, though I believe `data.table` has the edge for very large data sets.